# Scroll modal on show

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using jquery to show my Bootstrap modal, but am unable to scroll it until I manually click inside it.

I've tried focus():

```
  $('#action-modal-body').focus()
```

I've tried click():

```
  $('#action-modal-body').click()
```

I've even added a delay to account for the modal animation:

```
  setTimeout(function (){
    $('#action-modal-body').click()
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now with bootstrap 3 the events has change an can be achieved like this (plus a smooth animation to the top)

```
$('#modalIdHere').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#modalIdHere').animate({ scrollTop: 100 }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: This changes which part of the modal form is visible, but my scroll events I send with my mouse are not recognized until I click it.

Comment: you need to replace `#modalIdHere` with your modal id not your modal content id. so when ever modal show it will automatic scroll to given possition